# Calling a class from within another class PHP7

Tags: php, oop, php-7

I have an abstract class with all the common stuff in it (DB connections etc) and I could put the banners in there but I wanted them separate from the DB in their own class. This is what I have that works...

```
include "includes/abstract-class.php";
include "includes/extended-class.php";
include "includes/separate-class.php";

$separate = new SEPARATEClass();
$extended = new EXTENDEDClass($separate);
```

Then, in the abstract class...

```
abstract class ABSTRACTClass 
{

    public function __construct (SEPARATEClass $separate){
        $this->separate = $separate;
    }

    // This empty function is needed in order for there not to be fatal errors 
    // even though the function with the same name that actually has content is 
    // in the separate class...
    protected function draw_small_banner(){
    }
```

Then, in the extended class where I want to call the functions I can do something like this that calls the `draw_small_banner()` function from `SEPARATEClass()`...

```
class EXTENDEDClass extends ABSTRACTClass 
{

    parent::draw_small_banner();
```

I tried a few different ways of doing this from some other Stackoverflow questions but this was the only way I could get it to work. This is using PHP 7. Is there a better way that will work?

Also, it seems odd to me that this will only work if the empty functions are in the abstract class. If anyone can explain this or suggest a neater alternative I'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Anything that extends `ABSTRACTClass` and doesn't omit its constructor should have access to `$this->separate` since you've implicitly made it `public`

Comment: Thank you. Right, but `$this->separate->draw_small_banner();` would not work for me without having the empty function in the abstract class.

Comment: Well, I don't know. Does the `SEPARATEClass` have a `draw_small_banner` public, non-static method?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's public. This is it... `class SEPARATEClass {` then `public function draw_small_banner(){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, anything that extends `ABSTRACTClass` and doesn't omit its constructor should have access to `$this->separate`.

Assuming `SEPARATEClass` has something like

```
public function draw_small_banner() {
    // do some drawing or something
}
```

I would first make it a protected member of `ABSTRACTClass`...

```
abstract class ABSTRACTClass {
    protected $separate;

    public function __construct(SEPARATEClass $separate) {
        $this->separate = $separate;
    }
}
```

then, in your extending classes, you should have access to it

```
class EXTENDEDClass extends ABSTRACTClass {
    public function drawStuff() {
        $this->separate->draw_small_banner();
    }
}
```

Execution would look like

```
$separate = new SEPARATEClass();
$extended = new EXTENDEDClass($separate);
$extended->drawStuff();
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Other than the protected variable I believe that's what I had. My mind may have melted though. I'll try again tomorrow and come back with feedback.

Comment: If you absolutely want your child class to implement a method, I suggest removing the method from the abstract class and create and interface with the said method. Then implement your interface in your extendedClass.

Comment: Thank you. An interface is what the abstract class with the empty functions looks like. I guess it needs setting up in the current class, it can't just be imported. This makes sense and means that I'm not going crazy, I think. Thanks again.